# Where is the Action Log file of OpenStack Web UI on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, cloud, openstack

I have difficulty in finding the action log file of OpenStack Web UI on Ubuntu. Could someone help me?
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Srw2.png)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.openstack.org/openstack-ops/content/logging_monitoring.html (2nd hit when googling "action log file of openstack web UI on Ubuntu" right now, first hit is this question) says:

> Where Are the Logs?
>
> Most services use the convention of writing their log files to subdirectories of the `/var/log` directory ...

Answer (score 1):

it will appears in your web server log. In my case, horizon log is in either /var/log/apache2/horizon_error.log or /var/log/apache2/error.log